# Rails link_to with AJAX disable AJAX loading overlay for specific link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using Rails 4 and have a working AJAX overlay for all my `remote: true` links.

`application.js`

```
$('#loading-ajax').hide();
$('#overlay-ajax').hide();

$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $('#loading-ajax').show();
  $('#overlay-ajax').show();
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  $('#loading-ajax').hide();
  $('#overlay-ajax').hide();
});
```

The problem is that for one specific `link_to` I would NOT link to display this overlay. In the past I've used the `global: false` AJAX option, but am not sure where to set the AJAX options for a `remote: true` link.

Where can I set AJAX options for this link? Or how can I disable the general `ajaxStart` function for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do some slightly advanced things with jQuery and ajax alongside rails, I would suggest changing your strategy to make explicit jQuery ajax calls instead of using the Rails helper: `remote: true`.  Try something like this in your view:

```
<%= link_to 'Click Me', action_path, :class => 'my-great-link' %>

<script>
  $('.my-great-link').click( function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault;
    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).prop('href'), // this will grab 'action_path' or whatever your link_to points to
      global: false // prevent ajaxStart from being triggered
    });
  });
</script>
```